# Jquery UI slider not retaining the selected value if we refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery UI slider, it is working fine. But if i refresh the page the slider is going back to the default values instead of retaining the selected value. Please help me to fix this issue.

Javascript:

```
 var selected = $( "#selectedValue" ).html();

    $("#valueSlider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        range: "min",
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#selectedValue').html(ui.value);
            selected = ui.value;
        },
        value: selected,
    });
    $('#selectedValue').html($( "#valueSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="valueSliderContainer">
                <label>
                    Value: <span id="selectedValue">45</span>                                           
                    <div id="valueSlider"></div>
                </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats what refreshing the page does, refreshes everything on the page.. JS included.

Comment: You can bind the stored value to the user session through ajax and load any session-saved data on page-load.

Comment: It is not an issue, it comes from the stateless nature of HTTP. New request = new state.

Comment: One possible way out of it is using cookie to store the value, then use this stored value instead.

Comment: Refreshing the page will restart any scripts you have on the page from their default state. If you want information to be persistent, try storing the selected value in a cookie or local browser storage and then reading from that storage to determine the first slideshow element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you put your selected value in a storage, like client side storage e.g cookies etc, your slider will be set back to the default value. (That's what the refreshing does)

For using the cookies and setting the values here is a good tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp